# Office.js Content Add-In - Scoped Settings (Stored Within Individual Embedded `Content`)

Tags: javascript, office365, office-js

Office.js allows you to store document-level settings via `Office.context.document.settings`.

Is there a sandboxed settings store which is scoped to an **individual content**?

My use case is that I have a [content Add-In](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/dev/add-ins/design/content-add-ins) that adds a visualisation to Excel.  This visualisation is configured via user input, and it is those user-defined settings that I'd like to persist.

For example, a user may select certain axis scales, zoom levels and so forth - all of which I'd like to store within the respective content Add-In.

Upon re-loading the Excel file containing the content [i.e. the visualisation/chart] (or multiple contents), the settings are read from the store and are then used to bring the data visualisation back to the state where the user left off.

> How can I store settings/information that is scoped to an individually inserted [content Add-In](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/dev/add-ins/design/content-add-ins)?

**EDIT:** this question can also be answered by highlighting, for example, a hypothetical unique ID that Office assigns to each visualisation/content (thereby allowing me to scope the settings myself).

Comment: I may be misunderstanding the question, but any system of key-value pairs settings can be given structure by appending scope info to the key name. E.g., instead of keys like "background-color" and "font-size", you could store "marys-background-color", "marys-font-size", "joes-background-color", joes-font-size", etc.

Comment: Indeed, and taking the time to comment. The issue is that I cannot see any unique piece of information that identifies the inserted visualisation.

Comment: I meant "thanks for taking the time to comment". :)

Comment: If you want settings broken down by user, then one way or another you're going to have to make your users identify themselves. Do your users login to your add-in so you can get their identity? If not, how can the visualisation be "configured via user settings" as you say in your question?

Comment: It's a chart which users add to their Excel workbook. Much like a bar chart, I'd like users to be able to configure things like axes' scales and so forth - which are scoped to each individual chart.

Comment: Every Chart object has its own format, axes, series, etc. properties, so the ability to vary configuration with vary-by-chart is built into the APIs. See https://dev.office.com/reference/add-ins/excel/chart. But your original question implied that you want to vary-by-user. You can do that in the way that I explained in my first comment. So I think it's not really clear what it is you want to do. Can I ask you to add a lot more detail, and CONCRETENESS, to your question?

Comment: Thanks, I've expanded on a few points and made clear that what I am looking to do is persist user-defined settings which are scoped to individual content Add-In surface areas embedded in an Excel document.